# When run GITLAB CI then error migrate laravel with service mysql 5.7

Tags: laravel, gitlab, cicd, autodeploy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7onbY.png)

Please help me. When gitlab CI instance run then error migrate of laravel , can't connect host mysql
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRFO0.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please provide some code, not images. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First:
Use Docker with environment variables for deploy everyone :D

Second:
Make `cut .env` in CI script and show.
Your sed is not working right. It substitutes the variable name with the value, and not your data in the variable value.
Should be something like:

```
sed -i "s|DB_HOST=|DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}|g" .env
```

Third: Don't use `.env.example` for building `.env`. Build `.env` file from empty.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set up your MySQL properly. For services you have MySQL, but no port of it is exposed, NO MySQL root username, password, or database is set.
It should be something like...

```
services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
        ports:
          - 33306:3306
```

Then use that in your project Environment, try [this](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-github-actions) for a complete yml.

If you want SQLite instead of MySQL you can try [this](https://paulund.co.uk/test-laravel-with-github-actions)

Comment: Sorry. But i use gitlab and when i use service mysql:8.0 then worked with image php 7.2